# Store JWT compressed in cookie using Java

Tags: http, servlets, cookies, jwt

I am using Java servlet to return cookies with JWT information to client.

I return 2 cookies.

1 => Token_id, this cookie store the id_token

2 => refresh_token, this token store the refresh token to be send when the token is expired.

The problem is, these informations are too big, so the browser send this error:

431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

To resolve it, I would like to store the refresh_token compressed, and when I will use this information I will decompress.

I read about the compress and tried to use a GZIPCompress String, like this:

```
 public static String compress(final String str) throws IOException {
        if ((str == null) || (str.length() == 0)) {
            return null;
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
        gzip.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        gzip.flush();
        gzip.close();
        return obj.toString();
    }
```

When I add the compress String to cookie, I have this exception:

```
Illegal character in cookie value
```

I can not store the refresh_token in my server.
How can I compress a big String to store in a cookie? I need to decrease the size of value cookie.

Answer (score 1):

A cookie can only store strings, but you are storing binary data.

The result of the compression process is binary and is not representable using a string, even if you call `obj.toString();`. You would need to encode the result to base64 to get a string that could be stored in a cookie, but base64 increases the size about 30%, so I do not know if it makes sense in your case.

```
 //storage
 cookie = base64(gzip(str))

 //retrieval
 str = gunzip(base64decode(cookie))
```

The refresh token usually consists in a random string. May be you are including too much data?

Comment: Yes @pedrofb, my data is too large. I would like to compress the size of string, but I know that I need to store a String in cookie file.
Do you know if are there some method to encript a long string to short String and decript the same to original String?

Comment: Most browsers support cookies of up to 4096 bytes. Is not too much. I suggest you use localStorage instead of cookies and you will have a space of 5 to 10 mb depending on the browser. You probably do not need to compress

Comment: I used localStorage, I will not close the topic because the main subject it is decrease the size of string.